# Bash script parse xml elements to key=value pairs with XMLStarlet

Tags: xml, bash, sh, xmlstarlet

I have this xml file (filename: myFile.xml) with user's data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<params>
    <username>jDoe</username>
    <password>abc123</password>
    <firstname>John</firstname>
    <lastname>Doe</lastname>
    <email>jdoe@example.com</email>
    <country>Germany</country>
</params>
```

I can open it in my bash script and use a "for" loop to iterate it's contents:

```
for i in $(xmlstarlet select -t -v '/params/*' myFile.xml)
do
   echo $i
done
```

When I run it I get:

```
jDoe
abc123
John
Doe
jdoe@example.com
Germany
```

How can I associate each value with it's relative  name, and create a bash script variable like this:

```
username="jDoe"
password="abc123"
firstname="John"
lastname="Doe"
email="jdoe@example.com"
country="Germany"
```

In other words, for each tag I want to read it's name and it's value, and then create a bash variable out of that. ie:

```
tagname="value"
```

I prefer to loop through the tags because they are a lot more than this example and not always the same.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
xmlstarlet select --template --match "//params/*" --value-of "concat(name(),'=\"',text(),'\"')" -n file.xml
```

Output:

```
username="jDoe"
password="abc123"
firstname="John"
lastname="Doe"
email="jdoe@example.com"
country="Germany"
```

Comment: What does the `-n` before the file name?

Comment: @dawg: `-n` adds a new line after every key-value-pair.